# Replace all the <a> tags in string except with one specific ID using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regular-language

I have this HTML code:

```
$html='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    </head>

    <body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EmailMessage" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; width: 100% !important; height: 100%; line-height: 1.6em; background-color: #f6f6f6; margin: 0;" bgcolor="#f6f6f6">

        <table class="body-wrap" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; width: 100%; background-color: #f6f6f6; margin: 0;" bgcolor="#f6f6f6"><tr style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;"><td style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0;" valign="top"></td>
                <td class="container" width="600" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; display: block !important; max-width: 600px !important; clear: both !important; margin: 0 auto;" valign="top">
                    <div class="content" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; max-width: 600px; display: block; margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px;">
                        <table class="main" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; border-radius: 3px; background-color: #fff; margin: 0; border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;" bgcolor="#fff"><tr style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;">
                                <td class="alert alert-warning" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: top; color: #fff; font-weight: 500; text-align: center; border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0; background-color: #1ab394; margin: 0; padding: 20px;" align="center" bgcolor="#1ab394" valign="top">
                                    Following change has occurred in the 1st fault 4 notification.
                                </td>
                            </tr><tr style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;"><td class="content-wrap" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 20px;" valign="top">
                                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;"><tr style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;"><td id="notification-detail" class="content-block" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;" valign="top">
                                                <a class="btn-link removable no-padding" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="goToListingByType()">Fault</a>, <a class="btn-link no-padding" href="javascript:void(0);" 
    onclick="goToDetailPageByType()">1st fault 4 notification, 14077</a> Naveed Saleem has updated the Due date of this Activity to 23rd November, 2016
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;"><td class="content-block" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;" valign="top">
                                                <a href="{{URL}}" id="login-link" class="btn-primary" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; line-height: 2em; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; border-radius: 5px; text-transform: capitalize; background-color: #1ab394; margin: 0; border-color: #1ab394; border-style: solid; border-width: 10px 20px;">Login Whuntu</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr><tr style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;"><td class="content-block" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;" valign="top">
                                                Thanks for choosing Company Inc.
                                            </td>
                                        </tr></table></td>
                            </tr></table><div class="footer" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; width: 100%; clear: both; color: #999; margin: 0; padding: 20px;">
                            <table width="100%" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;">
                                <tr style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;">
                                    <td class="aligncenter content-block" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 12px; vertical-align: top; color: #999; text-align: center; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;" align="center" valign="top">Copyright © 2014-2016, Company Name, United Kingdom. All rights reserved.</td>
                                </tr></table></div></div>
                </td>
                <td style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0;" valign="top"></td>
            </tr></table></body>
</html>
';
```

I want to replace all `<a>` tags except those that have specific attribute ID.

I am total rookie in regex. Can anyone please help. I found this regex that replaces all the  tags based on class:

```
$html = preg_replace('/<(a).*?class="\s*(?:.*\s)?removable(?:\s[^"]+)?\s*"[^\>]*>(.*)<\/\1>/i', '\2', $html);
```

But I exactly want what I stated i.e replace all the `<a>` tags with span except for those that have specific ID.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: If you do a google search for "regex conditional substitute" you will come across syntax like this: `(?(?=regex)then|else)`. That should help you in the right direction.

Comment: This is not a job for regex, use DOMDocument with DOMXPath.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to parse a structured language, use this structure, don't parse it like a simple text. PHP provides build-in tools to parse HTML and XML:

- the `DOMDocument` class to build and edit the DOM tree
- the `DOMXPath` class to query the DOM tree

Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

// select all the link nodes that don't have an id attribute
// to discard a specific id, you can change the predicate to: not(@id="yourid")
$linkNodeList = $xp->query('//a[not(@id)]');

foreach ($linkNodeList as $linkNode) {
    // create a new span element where to store all children nodes of the link node
    $spanNode = $dom->createElement('span');
    // append each child node to the span node
    foreach($linkNode->childNodes as $childNode) {
        $spanNode->appendChild($childNode->cloneNode(true));
    }
    // replace the link node with the span node
    $linkNode->parentNode->replaceChild($spanNode, $linkNode);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```